# opening view in new tab in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I am using mvc3 and telerik mvc grid. In grid I gave custom command. When we click the command a new view should be opened in new tab. Say, view opened is "Home/Index" in which telerik grid is there and custome button inside the grid will open new view say "Posts/Index" in new tab 'post' is controller name and 'index' is action name.

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: What tab do you mean? telerik new tab or browser new tab?

Comment: At least I can't understand any of this. You want to open new tab that would have content coming from controller Posts and action Index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@{
Html.Telerik().Grid<Model>()
    .Name("Runs")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(r => r.ID))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
        //Ajax binding
                    .Ajax()
                    .Select("Run", "Management")
                )
            .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(r => r.Definition.Name).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(r => r.CreateTime);
            columns.Bound(r => r.FileName); 
            columns.Bound(r => r.Status);
            columns.Bound(r => r.CreatedBy);
            columns.Bound(r => r.ID).ClientTemplate(Html.ActionLink("View", "RunDetails", new { id = "<#= ID #>" }, new { @class = "t-grid-action t-button t-state-default t-grid-edit t-button-hover" }).ToString()).Width(200).Title("Commands").Filterable(false);
        })
    .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(20))
    .Sortable( sorting => sorting.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .Filterable()
    .Render();
}
```

Try this...